# Date based on day of year + year

Tags: javascript, datetime

Given a Year, and a day of that year, how can i get the full date? ex: `60/2014` = `March First 2014` and `61/2016` = `March First 2016`

notes: -year and day can be passed as separate parameters.
-result can be a regular Date instance, i just explicitally showed as text to alert for "leap year"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript has some pretty neat "magic":

```
var input = "60/2014";
var parts = input.split("/");
var d = new Date(parts[1],0,parts[0]);
```

That's right. 60th of January. JavaScript will automatically correct this to the first of March.

Comment: At least on chrome 33 on Mac that results in "Invalid Date".

Comment: I tested it on latest Chrome on Windows, and IE11, both worked. I'm pretty sure this is supposed to be a standard feature, so it's kinda strange that your browser does that...

Comment: Hm... may have figured out the problem.  Looks like a typo in the `new Date()` assignment.  Should be `parts[0]` and `parts[1]`.  Works with the correct indexing

Comment: It does work across browsers, with the index correction in place. We were so fast to comment, we didn't even notice the offset. Shame on us, guys :(